# JQuery Check for Checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, gridview, checkbox

The function always returns false, eventhough the checkbox is checked. I really couldn't crack down what i'm doing wrong. I'm using a checkbox to enable and disable the textbox in the gridview. However, it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the help. I have posted the html and jq code below.

HTML code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdFees" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" EmptyDataRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="gridItem" TabIndex="5">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkselect" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" 
                                    Width="15px" Checked="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".checkbox").click(function()
        {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
        {
            alert("true");
        }else
        {
            alert("false");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ASP.NET probably doesn't apply the value of `CssClass` to the check box itself, but to the generated label and/or container element.

Try using the [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Up vote, thank you so much.  This was driving me nuts. How did I miss this upon HTML inspection is beyond me.

Comment: Oh my gosh!  You just ended a bunch of hair pulling for me.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As the Grid doesnt apply the class to the checkbox you can do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".checkbox :checkbox").click(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chkselect").click(function(){
        if (this.checked) { // can also use $(this).is(':checked') as you do
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    }); // you code miss "});" here
});
```

You can also use the selector

`$(':input:checkbox')` or `$('input:checkbox')`

Comment: thanks for the reply...but still it doesn't work. the alert always shows false.